# BitmapToBase64 Android Studio

Tags: java, android, camera

I tyied to post a base64 string transformed from a preview picture to a server.
To make this string shorter, I tried to reduce the size of the bitmap. But after that, I found that the length of string did not decrease.
The following is the code.

```
 @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        int imageFormat = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
        int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
        int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

        // TODO: Arguments?
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
        YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(mData, imageFormat, w, h, null);
        Log.e("Image", "width:" + w + " height:" + h);

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, outputStream);
            Bitmap raw_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outputStream.toByteArray(), 0, outputStream.size());
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreviewFrame: origin_raw_bitmap:" + ToBase64.bitmapToBase64(raw_bitmap));
//            raw_bitmap = BitmapProcess.scaleBitmap(raw_bitmap, 50, 50);
            raw_bitmap = BitmapProcess.compressImage(raw_bitmap);
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreviewFrame: new_raw_bitmap:" + ToBase64.bitmapToBase64(raw_bitmap));

            String base64_global = ToBase64.bitmapToBase64(raw_bitmap);

            login(myurl, base64_global, new okhttp3.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                    Log.d(TAG + "Failure", "onFailure:err");
//                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection refused!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    assert response.body() != null;
                    String result = response.body().string();

                    Log.d(TAG + "Response", "out result===" + result);
                    Log.d(TAG + "Response", response.code() + "");

                    if (JudgeAns(result)) {
                        Log.e("Response", "Blind");

                        Looper.prepare();
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SurfaceViewCallback.getInstacne().context, "Get the Blind way.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        Looper.loop();

                    } else {
                        Log.e("Response", "Others");
                        Looper.prepare();
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SurfaceViewCallback.getInstacne().context, "Can not find the Blind way.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        Looper.prepare();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onPreviewFrame: Fail" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
public static Bitmap compressImage(Bitmap image) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        int options = 100;
        while (baos.toByteArray().length / 1024 > 100) { 
            baos.reset();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, options, baos);
            options -= 10;
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream isBm = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isBm, null, null);
    }
```

These is the information in the Logcat in Android Studio.

String before bitmap reduced:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FRoh.png)

String after bitmap reduced:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0sg.png)

Comment: `I tried to reduce the size of the bitmap. ` Please tell what you consider to be the size of a bitmap.

Comment: `int options = 100;` You name that options. But hey are no options. Only a quality parameter.

Comment: `options -= 10;` Does it never happen that options become negative? When does the loop end then? You saying that the sting does not get shorter implies that the loop ends.

Comment: Please tell all the values of baos.toByteArray().length.

Comment: Log.d is not the way to compare the size of two base64 encoded strings as Log.d does not print the whole sting if the string is long. Only the start of it. So better compare the lenght of the strings.

Comment: `I tried to reduce the size of the bitmap.` Whatever you mean by that... I would not reduce the quality to begin with but its resolution. So scale it down instead.

Comment: `String before bitmap reduced: enter image description here` It is unclear what we should see in those pictures. You should have told that.

Comment: Further you are not uploading a bitmap but a jpg file. And not just a jpg file as is but base64 encoded. That is 30 % more then if you would upload thye jpg itself. Are you forced to upload images base64 encoded by someone?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. After printing the length of string, I found that after using this function, the length of string becoming even longer. I checked the function again and found that the condition set in compression loop is error. And now I fixed it.What a stupid mistake i made!

Comment: And different binary encoding methods may be used on the machine, so base64 is used. Thank you again!